# Highcharts graph start from zero on yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have updated highcharts lib to version 4.0.4 and have some changeses on graph.
When I have array with 10 zero values, my graph line is centered vertically.

How can I change highcharts options to have a line along the xAxis when all my points are zeros, without setting max value to yaxis.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: I have this Options for chart. 
        var options = {
            title: {
                text: some title
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%b %e',
                    week: '%b %e'
                },
                tickPixelInterval: 170
            },
            tooltip: {
                }
            }
        };

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean please create http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have found the answer )))

http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/series-with-0-zero-values-are-vertically-centered-t30408/

Thank You for trying to help

Comment: good news you welcom :)